# How to simulate Ctrl/Meta keyDown on Firefox using browser.performActions?

Tags: webdriver-io, geckodriver

Does anyone know what adjustments need to be made to this code to execute correctly on FireFox?

Here is my test code, it can execute Control + Click items on chrome. But when executed on FireFox(geckodriver v0.30.0 win64), the effect of the test code becomes Click items. I checked the doc https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver/#performactions, but not found any clue.

```
const ctlKey = '\uE009';  
browser.performActions([
    {
      actions: [{ type: 'keyDown', value: ctlKey }],
      id: 'press',
      type: 'key',
    },
  ]);

  // multiple Control + Click.
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.click();
  });

  // release
  browser.performActions([
    {
      actions: [{ type: 'keyUp', value: ctlKey }],
      id: 'release',
      type: 'key',
    },
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like FireFox can't support this way. It only works when I use performActions to do clicks together with pressing and releasing the Control.

```
const clickActions = [
    {
      actions: [
        {
          duration: 0,
          type: 'pointerMove',
          x: Math.floor(item.x),
          y: Math.floor(item.y),
        },
        { duration: 200, type: 'pause' },
        { button: 0, type: 'pointerDown' },
        { duration: 200, type: 'pause' },
        { button: 0, type: 'pointerUp' },
      ],
      id: 'click_item_1',
      parameters: { pointerType: 'mouse' },
      type: 'pointer',
    },
    ...// more clicks
];
let allActions = [];

allActions.push({
    actions: [{ type: 'keyDown', value: '\uE009' }],
    id: 'hold_ctrl',
    type: 'key',
});

allActions = allActions.concat(clickActions);

allActions.push({
    actions: [{ type: 'keyUp', value: '\uE009' }],
    id: 'release_ctrl',
    type: 'key',
});
browser.performActions(allActions);
```

Comment: what code is for command key in mac chrome?